# Symfony2 return invalid object

Tags: symfony, object, doctrine

I really don't understand why it doesn't work, 'cause similar code of the same Entity runs perfectly.

I've this function in my "ConnexioRepository" that I'm 90% sure it works well:

```
public function findPort($port)
    {
            $em = $this->getEntityManager();
            $consulta = $em->createQuery('
            SELECT c FROM FrontendBundle:Connexio c 
            WHERE c.port = :port
            ');
        $consulta->setParameter('port', $port);
        return $consulta->getOneOrNullResult(); 
    }
```

And this in my FrontendBundle:

```
 $connexioTMP = $em->getRepository('FrontendBundle:Connexio')->findPort($port->getId());
```

I'm sure $port->getId() works, but when "findPort" tries to give me the required object (only happens when there's a match in my DB), all seems to stop working. It's like:

```
$id=$port->getId();
//$connexioTMP = $em->getRepository('FrontendBundle:Connexio')->findPort($port->getId());
echo($id);
```

result: It shows me the id of that object

but

```
$id=$port->getId();
$connexioTMP = $em->getRepository('FrontendBundle:Connexio')->findPort($port->getId());
echo($id);
```

result: nothing. 500 internal server error.

The same happens if I put:

```
$connexioTMP = $em->getRepository('FrontendBundle:Connexio')->findOneByPort($port->getId());
```

Everything below this sentence, doesn't work. I don't know if it could be related with the fact that "port" is a foreign key.

I've called another functions of this Repository and worked well.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should start by finding the actual error message. Look in the application log or enable dev mode.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem: 
request.CRITICAL: ReflectionException: Class Cisco\FrontendBundle\Entity\Cisco\FrontendBundle\Entity\Connexio does not exist (uncaught exception)


It's repeating the path for the Entity. I've searched this error but I don't understand it's solutions. u_u